# View goes off while using $http.get in angular? ng-view goes off when 401 is returned as response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

I have a authentication code, when I get a success message as in 200 reponse status then its fine but if I get 401 the page should show error as I have set some error status but this does not happen and I get the view also refreshes and turns out to be blank. Please help

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http','$rootScope','$route','$localStorage', function ($scope, $location, $http, $rootScope,$route, $localStorage) {
    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.ipsenData = {};
    $scope.username="";
    $scope.password="";
    $scope.invalidUser="";

    /*Functionalities of the Application*/
    $scope.login = function () {
        $http.post('/ipsen/login', {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if(status===200){
                console.log("Login Successful");
                $http.get('/ipsen/getrole?userName='+$scope.username)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if(data.rows[0].RoleName==="Ipsen Manager"){
                        var data = data.rows[0];
                        /*Username and Role Storage*/
                         $localStorage.username=$scope.username;
                         $localStorage.FirstName=data.FirstName;
                         $localStorage.LastName=data.LastName;
                         $localStorage.OrganizationName=data.OrganizationName;
                         $localStorage.RoleName=data.RoleName;
                         $localStorage.Email=data.Email;


                         $location.path('/customers').replace();
                    }
                    else{
                         var data = data.rows[0];
                        /*Username and Role Storage*/
                         $localStorage.FirstName=data.FirstName;
                         $localStorage.LastName=data.LastName;
                         $localStorage.OrganizationName=data.OrganizationName;
                         $localStorage.RoleName=data.RoleName;
                         $localStorage.Email=data.Email;
                         $location.path('/furnacelist/'+$scope.username+"/"+"customer").replace();
                    }
                    /**/
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if(status === 401){
                $scope.invalidUser="Please Enter Valid Username & Password";
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Initially page has a view where you can see the login form and all. After I click login the view changes all together.

Comment: It looks like you need to set up an interceptor to handle this. See the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), also the article by [Lukas Ruebbelke](http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an interceptor like the following, which may help so that on a 401 your user will simply be stuck on the login page.

```
function APIInterceptor($rootScope, $q) {
    var service = this;
    service.responseError = function(response) {
      console.log("in responseError", response); // just to see the error initially
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
        return $q.reject(response);
      }

      return response;
    };
  }
```

Then you put the interceptor in your configuration file that handles the routes.

```
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
```

With the following code using `rootScope.$on` within `.run`.

```
  $rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function() {
      // ... some code to handle tokens, cookies, whatever ... set to null
      $location.path('/login');
    });
```

There are other bits I have left out, but I think you get the point. Basically, you want to add an interceptor in there to handle your requests and responses.